# Simple MERN Axios calls don't (and have never) worked for me. Consistent 404 Error. Possibly due to File Structure

Tags: reactjs, axios, mern

I've been told that Axios is how you get React to talk to an api (external or internal). So far, I have specifically only received 404 errors whenever I try to implement Axios calls.

Here is the axios call in `client/src/App.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import API from "./utils/API";

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    recipes: []
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    API.getRecipes("milk") /* This is supposed to call the getRecipes 
                              function in API.js with "milk" as the only 
                              parameter (ie - Search the api for "milk" 
                              related recipes). */

    .then(res => this.setState({recipes: res.data}))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render(){
  return (
    <div>
      {
        this.state.recipes.map(recipe => {
          return(
            <p>
              {recipe.title} // All recipe names are then set to a p tag
            </p>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now, this calls `API.js` in the "utils" folder:

```
import axios from "axios";

// Function that takes the parameter and is supposed to send it to the 
   /api/recipes route

export default {
  getRecipes: function(query) { 

    return axios.get("/api/recipes", { params: { q: query } });

  }
};
```

The relevant api route (`/api/recipes`) is located in a folder named "routes" outside of the "src" folder. This file is the only item inside the folder.

```
const axios = require("axios");
const router = require("express").Router();

/* As you can see, this sends the request to "recipepuppy.com" with the 
   relevant query ("milk").*/

router.get("/recipes", (req, res) => {
    axios.get("http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/", {params: req.query})
    .then(({data: {results}}) => {res.json(results)})
    .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Going even further out, here is the `server.js` file (outside of the "client" folder) that determines the routes:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();
const apiRoutes = require("./routes/apiRoutes"); // *********

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}

app.use("/api", apiRoutes); // *********

app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`API server now listening on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

As far as I can tell, everything is set up perfectly. However, every single time I boot up the server, the browser console error pops up and says:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/recipes?q=milk 404 (Not Found)
```

Even though `server.js` directly ties to the `apiRoutes` folder, and the axios call within `API.js` calls the exact same route that would result from going to the `/api` route, then the `/recipes` route within `/api` (resulting in `/api/recipes`).

If anybody here can tell me what is going on and how to fix it, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have "proxy" set in my dependencies (`package.json`) in the `client` folder.

Once I set "proxy" to "localhost:3001" (the same as my initial `server.js` port value) and restarted the server, it worked immediately.